# Spectrum, eigenvectors and diagonalizability for matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to prove or disprove those 3 statements (so find a counterexample if wrong). It seems that a) and b) are the same because each eigenvalue has one eigenvector right ? I think that c) is correct too. For a), we can use the fact that the determinant of a matrix equals the product of its eigenvalues. Similarly, the trace of the matrix equals the sum of its eigenvalues.

[image]

Comment: a)  and b) are not the same : for instance all nilpotent matrices have the same spectrum, but they don't have the same kernel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a), we have:
$$
\det (A-\lambda I)=\det (A-\lambda I)^T=\det (A^T-\lambda I^T)=\det (A^T-\lambda I)
$$
so $A$ and $A^T$ have the same characteristic polynomial, than the same eigenvalues.

b) is not equivalent to a) and it is not true . As a counterexample consider the matrices:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&1\\
0&0
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad 
\begin{bmatrix}
1&0\\
1&0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

For c), note that if $A$ is diagonalizable we have:
$$
A=PDP^{-1}
$$
with $D$ diagonal, so:
$$
A^T=(PDP^{-1})^T=(P^{-1})^TD^{T}P^T=(P^T)^{-1} D P^T
$$
where that last step is done because the transpose of the inverse is the inverse of the transpose and the transpose of  diagonal matrix is the same matrix. So $A^T$ is diagonalizable.